# Execute weblogic "Lock and Edit" in unix command line

Tags: unix, console, weblogic

I'm running weblogic in unix, I would like to automated processes by executing tasks in the command line, for example i would like to update a deployed project without the need of accessing the weblogic console, rather i would want to run a command that will do the job, so my initial challenge is, how do i run "Lock and Edit" in the command line? or i should ask, what is the console doing behind the scene when I'm running "Lock and Edit" ?

Answer (score 0):

To deploy/undeploy application from the command line, you can use the weblogic.Deployer class. See that [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24443/wldeployer.htm#DEPGD318) for details.
WebLogic Server has its own scripting language based on Jython (python in a JVM) you can use to computerize any configuration action. WLST is described in this [documentation](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/fmw/wls/12c/06-WLST--4474/cmdline.htm).

Answer (score 0):

When you do lock and edit it creates a nonexclusive lock to the domain and same can be achieved with command line as below:

Generate a client jar from weblogic using below:

Change directories to the server/lib directory.

```
cd WL_HOME/server/lib
Use the following command to create wlfullclient.jar in the server/lib directory:

java -jar ../../modules/com.bea.core.jarbuilder_X.X.X.X.jar
where X.X.X.X is the version number of the jarbuilder module in the WL_HOME/server/lib directory.
```

For example:

```
 java -jar ../../../modules/com.bea.core.jarbuilder_1.0.1.0.jar
```

You can now copy and bundle the wlfullclient.jar with client applications.
Add the wlfullclient.jar to the client application’s classpath.

once this is done use the below command to automate the deployment:

```
 export CLASSPATH='location where your client jar resides'
 java -cp $CLASSPATH weblogic.Deployer -adminurl ADMIN_URL:PORT -username weblogic -password weblogic1! -deploy app.war -name appname -targets AdminServer -debug - usenonexclusivelock
```